# Unable to throw custom exceptions in setter methods in the main application

Tags: java

I am trying to add in custom exception into setters in my class objects.
While doing so, I am getting error in my `Main.java` file in which the error is as follows:

```
error: unreported exception StudentException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    pgs.setThesisMark(-75);
```

In my code, the `thesisMark` should be in the range of 0-100 (the input -75 is simply for testing purposes)
One way that seems to rectify the issue is by implementing `try...catch...` to the `setThesisMark` in main(), however it does not catch/ display the exception message.

Here are my codes:

Main.java

```
class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    PostGradStudent pgs = new PostGradStudent(
      "Jack", "Bauer", 70);
    
    System.out.println("Before change:");
    System.out.println(pgs.getThesisMark());
 
    pgs.setThesisMark(75);
    System.out.println("After change:");
    System.out.println(pgs.getThesisMark());
 
  }
}
```

PostGradStudent.java

```
public class PostGradStudent extends Student
{
    private int thesisMark;
 
    public PostGradStudent(String firstName, String lastName, 
        int thesisMark)
    {
        // parameters for Student class
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.thesisMark = thesisMark;
    }
 
    public int getThesisMark()
    {
      return thesisMark;
    }
 
    public void setThesisMark(int markInput) throws StudentException
    {
        if (markInput>0 || markInput<100)
        {
           thesisMark = markInput;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new StudentException("Invalid input...");
        }
    }
}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

StudentException.java

```
public class StudentException extends Exception
{
    public StudentException(String msg)
    {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Additionally, is it ideal to place exception for all setter methods?

Comment: You can also check out the Oracle Tutorial on [Catching and Handling Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Surround the statement with a Try-Catch.

```
class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    PostGradStudent pgs = new PostGradStudent(
      "Jack", "Bauer", 70);
    
    System.out.println("Before change:");
    System.out.println(pgs.getThesisMark());
 
 try {
    pgs.setThesisMark(75);
    System.out.println("After change:");
    System.out.println(pgs.getThesisMark());
 } 
 catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Sorry for the poor formatting. Hope this helped!

Comment: Catching `Exception` is nearly always the wrong choice - and it most definitely is here.